# Why awk if conditional matching is wrong

Tags: shell, awk

In my project, I have two files.

The content userid is :

```
6534
4524
4522
6635
```

The content userpwinfo.txt is:

```
nsgg315_RJ:x:4520:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg315_RJ:/bin/bash
nsgg316_ZJY:x:4521:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg316_ZJY:/bin/bash
nsgg317_CPA:x:4522:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg317_CPA:/bin/bash
nsgg318_ZRL:x:4523:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg318_ZRL:/bin/bash
nsgg319_YYM:x:4524:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg319_YYM:/bin/bash
```

Now I want to print the username which id is in userid. I writed a bash shell like:

```
for i in $(cat userid)
do
  #username=`awk -F: '{if($3=="$i") print $1}' /root/userpwinfo.txt`
  #username=`awk -F: '$3=="$i" {print $1}' /root/userpwinfo.txt`
  #username=`awk -F: '{if($3~/$i/) print $1}' /root/userpwinfo.txt`
   username=`awk -F: '{if($3==$i) print $1}' /root/userpwinfo.txt`
   echo $username
done
```

But unlucky, it shows nothing. The correct result should be:

```
nsgg319_YYM
nsgg317_CPA
```

I have tried in command line:

awk -F: '{if($3==4524) print $1}' /root/userpwinfo.txt

It is OK

Maybe if($3==$i) is wrong in shell, Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$i` is the shell variable, but it's inside the quotation mark `'` so `awk` will try to interpret it instead of the shell.

Try this:

```
username=`awk -F: '{if($3=='$i') print $1}' /root/userpwinfo.txt`
```

Note that the `$i` is between `'` marks, meaning it's outside of the block that will be interpreted by `awk`, meaning it should be interpreted by the shell.

Also note that if you have an empty line in the input file, your awk command would be `if($3==)` which is invalid and will yield an error.

I'd like to comment also that `awk` is meant to have a filter and an execution block. You shouldn't need to write an `if` inside a block, unless you want something unusual. Meaning, your command would be more appropriately written as:

```
username=`awk -F: '($3=='$i'){print $1}' /root/userpwinfo.txt`
```

Note that even this is not a very good solution, but you already have much to think about with only these changes. When you're more familiar with `awk` or getting more professional, come back and check the comments. ;)

Comment: Your answer is very professional, thank you very much

Comment: This is safer: `awk -F: -v var="$i" '$3 == var {print $1}' file` -- this way you're not leaving the variable unquoted (and exposed to word splitting and path expansion), and you're letting awk take care of its internal quoting.

Comment: What glenn said. Using string concatenation to generate code is an antipattern -- escalates things that would just be runtime errors to security bugs, since a value of `$i` could now contain a string like `system("...")` that tells `awk` to run a shell.

Comment: I know. I didn't want to overwhelm the OP, I had already mentioned 3 new concepts to them. My main goal was that they would understand what was happening in their code. I personally usually like to understand what's going wrong with my code, regardless of having a solution or not, so I provide that to others. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If username is what you needed using the 2 files, you could try

```
$ cat userpwinfo.txt
nsgg315_RJ:x:4520:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg315_RJ:/bin/bash
nsgg316_ZJY:x:4521:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg316_ZJY:/bin/bash
nsgg317_CPA:x:4522:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg317_CPA:/bin/bash
nsgg318_ZRL:x:4523:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg318_ZRL:/bin/bash
nsgg319_YYM:x:4524:100::/home-gg/users/nsgg319_YYM:/bin/bash

$ cat userid.txt
6534
4524
4522
6635

$ awk -F":" ' { if( NR==FNR ) { a[$3]=$1; next } ;  if(a[$1]) print a[$1] }' userpwinfo.txt userid.txt
nsgg319_YYM
nsgg317_CPA
```